# How to add annotations above ArrayList<String> | Hibernate (Jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist, entity, derby

i want to create derby Tables to 2 enities:
entity A , entity B.

In the "A" entity i have `ArrayList<String>`.
In the "A" entity i have `ArrayList<MyEnum>`.

Which annotations(@) i should to add above this ArrayList ,
in order that the tables will be built correctly?

**Entity A:**

```
@Entity(name = "A_Table")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @????????????????
    private ArrayList<String> myListString;
    .....
    .....
}
```

**Entity B:**

```
@Entity(name = "B_Table")
public class B extends A implements Serializable {

       public enum B_Enum { a, b , c}; 

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @????????????????
       private ArrayList<B_Enume> myListEnum;
       ....
       ...


    }
```

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: You may not use ArrayList. You must use List or Set. Programming to interfaces is mandatory in JPA. Hibernate is documented, and explains how associations between entities must be declared. Read the doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Thank you  @JBNizet. Truth is I do not aspire to be an expert Hibernate at the moment, and I just would love to solving these two specific points. 
Would you please show me an example of my code - what exactly to write?

Comment: This is very far from being at expert level. If you're not willing to learn anything about the technologies you're using, you won't go anywhere, and I don't feel like helping you staying ignorant.

Comment: @JBNizet
thank! i understand what i should do and it's work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with JPA 2 I think that you can use @ElementCollection to map it.

Here is an example:

> http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/elementcollection_hibernate_annotation

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this:

```
@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=B_Enume.class)
private ArrayList<B_Enume> myListEnum;
```